# Can I upload Knoppix kernel source to github?

Tags: licenses, github, gpl, knoppix

I'd like to be able to browse the Knoppix source code for my learning reference without having to copy it to every machine I use.I'd also like to discuss it with classmates. As you know, pre-github source code access was inconvenient to say the least. Currently Knoppix is only available as a traditional download.

I know Knoppix is released under the GPL, but I don't want to jump to conclusions without asking someone who knows a bit more about technology licensing than me.

Comment: Knoppix as a whole is *not* (and can not be) released under the GNU GPL. But if you are interesting in kernel only, then yes, [Linux®](https://kernel.org), which is the kernel Knoppix use, is mostly GPLv2-covered (not v3, the @DigitalTrauma have cited). But are you sure, that you need the very version of Linux that is supplied in Knoppix? Does not vanilla Linux (which [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)) suit your needs?

Comment: The vanilla Linux is too complicated for me to understand. I just want to see the essentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but I think the answer is yes.  From [GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)

> 4. Conveying Verbatim Copies.
>
> You may convey verbatim copies of the Program's source code as you receive it, in any medium, provided that you conspicuously and appropriately publish on each copy an appropriate copyright notice; keep intact all notices stating that this License and any non-permissive terms added in accord with section 7 apply to the code; keep intact all notices of the absence of any warranty; and give all recipients a copy of this License along with the Program.